# What is the right sign to show in a retail shop

Tags: syntactic-analysis

Let us see the signs shown in the images below.

What is the right one to show in a retail shop, #1 or #2?

In case #2 doesn't it seem as if the cashier may **or may not** give us a receipt?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Just please don't use a yellow background on the sign!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Neither form is free of sin; a more-proper form is:

> If you would like a receipt, please tell cashier.

Here is a scenario suggested by the second sign, which says, "Please ask cashier if you would like a receipt":

> *Customer:* Would I like a receipt?
>   *Cashier:* Let me consult my crystal ball.

Answer (score 4):

Both forms mean exactly the same thing but would be better written as

> Please ask the cashier if you would like a receipt

or

> If you would like a receipt, please ask the cashier.

This suggests that a receipt would not normally be given unless you request for it.

Answer (score 3):

One could quibble that #2 could be taken to mean that the cashier will inform you whether you want a receipt or not, i.e. that it means that you would go to the cashier and say, "Do I want a receipt?" But in this context that meaning seems pretty unlikely, so I don't think it would cause any confusion.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any difference in meaning there. Its clear that the sign is instructing customers to ask the cashier for a receipt if they want one. Keep in mind, companies are required to provide receipts in most places so that removes the doubt that the customer would reject the request.

PS: The only real issue I see is how god-awful the color scheme is. Seriously, that hurts my eyes and I hope you aren't considering using that in a retail environment.